# How to get XML attribute value's using 'xsl:apply-templates' in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, apply-templates

I have the following XML and would like to get the value of XML attribute `code="MA"` from `<FullNameVerifiesToAddress>` node and `<FullNameVerifiesToSSN>` node into the node `<Summary>`.

```
<PreciseIDServer>
    <Header>
        <ReportDate>09042018</ReportDate>
        <ReportTime>235641</ReportTime>
    </Header>
    <Summary>
        <TransactionID>1421957889</TransactionID>
        <InitialDecision>ACC</InitialDecision>
        <FinalDecision>ACC</FinalDecision>
        <CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
            <FullNameVerifiesToAddress code="MA"/>
            <FullNameVerifiesToSSN code="MA"/>
        </CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
    </Summary>
</PreciseIDServer>
```

I use the following XSLT right now to get the `<ReportTime>` from `<Header>` node into `<summary>` but I also need the above mentioned attributes in the Summary node.

```
<xsl:template match="Summary">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ancestor::PreciseIDServer/Header/ReportTime | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the XML i want as OUTPUT should be something like

```
<PreciseIDServer>
    <Header>
        <ReportDate>09042018</ReportDate>
        <ReportTime>235641</ReportTime>
    </Header>
    <Summary>
        <TransactionID>1421957889</TransactionID>
        <InitialDecision>ACC</InitialDecision>
        <FinalDecision>ACC</FinalDecision>
        <ReportTime>235641</ReportTime>
        <FullNameVerifiesToAddress>MA </FullNameVerifiesToAddress>
        <FullNameVerifiesToSSN> MA </FullNameVerifiesToSSN>
        <CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
            <FullNameVerifiesToAddress code="MA"/>
            <FullNameVerifiesToSSN code="MA"/>
        </CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
    </Summary>
</PreciseIDServer>
```

Comment: It would help enormously if you show the expected resulting XML for your input.

Comment: edited the question by adding the desired output aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to push some nodes through a second mode as you want to output them once uncopied while you also want to transform them, so a minimal XSLT 3 solution would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Summary">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ancestor::PreciseIDServer/Header/ReportTime | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="code-att-to-content"/>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid/*" mode="code-att-to-content">
        <xsl:copy>{@code}</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqL

For XSLT 2 you would need to replace [the `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy)

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and [the text value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates) `{@code}` with an `<xsl:value-of select="@code"/>`.

For XSLT 1 you need the same changes as for XSLT 2 but additionally need to put a name on the identity template (i.e. change `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">` to `<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">`) and replace the use of `<xsl:next-match/>` with `<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>`.

Comment: And for XSLT 1.0 (which hopefully they are not using!) you would have to replace `xsl:next-match` too

Comment: @TimC, thanks for that hint, I have spelled out the necessary changes in an edit.